# How to activate application background in Photoshop CS5 on the mac?

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop

I am used to Photoshop CS5 on Windows where the program has a gray background. I don't see my desktop when the program is open. On the Mac t hough, Photoshop is transparent and always fullscreen. I see the desktop icons and I find this very annoying. Also, I can't attach a canvas window to the application like I can do in Photoshop on Windows.

Can I activate an application background on in Photoshop in the Mac which will cover my desktop the way every application does when it is opened up fullscreen?

Answer (score 12):

To achieve a look like on Windows, activate this: Window > Application Frame

Comment: This is great, why it is not activated by default is one of the Mac mysteries

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to use [Isolator](http://willmore.eu/software/isolator). Or I just use a solid gray desktop picture, keep other applications hidden, and the desktop empty.